# Accordion menu submenu overlaying menu rather than expanding it

Tags: javascript, css, menu, umbraco7

I have a responsive site running on Umbraco 7. When viewed on a mobile the main menu changes from the dropdown version on the desktop site to an accordion style menu. I have a javascript script operating so that when you touch the arrow to the side of a menu item that submenu appears. However, instead of appearing between the menu item and the next menu item, expanding the menu as a whole, the submenu overlays the main menu and is semi-transparent, so that you can see the menu behind it.

The script is adding the properties, `display: block; visibility: visible; and opacity: 1;` to the `<ul>` element that contains the submenu, and the `<li>` elements have `display: block;` also.

Can anyone suggest why this is happening?

EDIT:

Html as rendered on the mobile site:

```
<ul>

    <li class="current">
        <a href="/">Home</a>
        <span id="mainMenuIcon" class="fa fa-bars menuIcon"></span>
    </li>

        <li class="mainMenuItem">
            <a href="/about-us/">About us</a>

                <span id="1259" class="fa fa-caret-down menuIcon subMenuOpener"></span>
                <ul>
                        <li><a href="/about-us/our-people/">Our People</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/about-us/who-we-were-and-are/">Who we were and are</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/about-us/our-houses/">Our Houses</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/about-us/annual-reports/">Annual Reports</a></li>
                </ul>

        </li>
        <li class="mainMenuItem">
            <a href="/being-a-tenant/">Being a Tenant</a>

                <span id="1293" class="fa fa-caret-down menuIcon subMenuOpener"></span>
                <ul>
                        <li><a href="/being-a-tenant/asbestos/">Asbestos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/being-a-tenant/being-safe-secure/">Being Safe &amp; Secure</a></li>
                </ul>

        </li>
        <li class="mainMenuItem">
            <a href="/news/">News</a>

                <span id="1305" class="fa fa-caret-down menuIcon subMenuOpener"></span>
                <ul>
                        <li><a href="/news/community-garden/">Community Garden</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/news/football-team/">Football Team</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/news/health-centre/">Health Centre</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/news/another-news-item/">Another News Item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/news/one-more-news-item/">One more news item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/news/a-further-news-item/">A further news item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/news/yet-more-news/">Yet more news</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/news/news-news-news/">News, news, news</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/news/how-much-more-news-is-there/">How much more news is there?</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/news/the-final-news-item/">The final news item?</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/news/the-final-news-item/">The final news item?</a></li>
                </ul>

        </li>
        <li class="mainMenuItem">
            <a href="/contact-us/">Contact Us</a>


        </li>
        <li class="mainMenuItem">
            <a href="/location/">Location</a>


        </li>
</ul>
```

CSS from main stylesheet that refers to the navigation:

```
nav {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
background-color: var(--darkest-color);
}

nav > ul > li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    margin: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    padding: 15px 8px 13px 8px;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: var(--lightest-color);
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    font-style: italic;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    width: 200px;
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.3s ease;
}

nav ul li:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid var(--lightest-color);
    background-color: var(--site-grey);
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

nav ul li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    padding: 20px 3px;
    background-color: var(--site-grey);
    border-bottom: 2px solid var(--lightest-color);
}

nav ul li ul li a {
    color: var(--lightest-color);
}

nav li.current {
    background-color: var(--site-grey);
    border-bottom: 2px solid var(--lightest-color);
}

nav li.current > a {
    color: var(--lightest-color);
    font-style: italic;
}
```

CSS from the responsive stylesheet that alters the above for the mobile site:

```
nav > ul > li {
        float: none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding-top: 15px;
    }

    nav > br {
        display: none;
    }

    nav ul ul {
        position: relative;
        top: 15px;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 0;
    }

    nav > ul > li {
        padding: 15px 0 13px 0;
    }

    nav ul li:hover {
        border-bottom: none;
        background-color: inherit;
    }   

    nav ul li:hover > ul {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    nav li.current {
        background-color: inherit;
        border-bottom: none;
    }

    .mainMenuItem {
        display: none;
    }

    .menuIcon {
        display: inline;
        position: relative;
        top: -5px;
        z-index: 1;
        float: right;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 0px;
        width; 0px;
    }
```

Javascript that displays a submenu when the arrowhead is clicked on a main menu item:

```
function activateSubMenuIcon(elementId) {
    var x = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
    var t = document.createTextNode("document.getElementById("
                                    + elementId
                                    +").onclick = function() {"
                                    + "if (document.getElementById("
                                    + elementId
                                    + ").className === 'fa fa-caret-down menuIcon subMenuOpener') {"
                                    + "document.getElementById("
                                    + elementId
                                    + ").className = 'fa fa-caret-up menuIcon subMenuOpener';"
                                    + "document.getElementById("
                                    + elementId
                                    + ").nextElementSibling.setAttribute('style','display: block !important; opacity: 1 !important; visibility: visible !important;');"
                                    + "} else {"
                                    + "document.getElementById("
                                    + elementId
                                    + ").className = 'fa fa-caret-down menuIcon subMenuOpener';"
                                    + "document.getElementById("
                                    + elementId
                                    + ").nextElementSibling.style.display = 'none';}}");
    x.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(x);
}


var subMenuOpeners = document.getElementsByClassName("subMenuOpener");
var numberOfSubMenuOpeners = subMenuOpeners.length;

for ( i=0 ; i < numberOfSubMenuOpeners ; i++ ) {

        var spanId = document.getElementsByClassName("subMenuOpener")[i].id;

        activateSubMenuIcon(spanId);

}
```

Comment: Since posting I have added !important to the `<ul>` properties but it hasn't helped.

Comment: Do you have the HTML and CSS you are using?